# Ring with non-trivial idempotent splitting as product of two rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

If a commutative ring $T$ has a non-trivial idempotent $e$, then it is easy to show that $f:T \rightarrow R\times S$ defined by $f(t)=(et,(1-e)t)$ is a ring isomorphism. My question is how to prove the converse, viz., if a commutative ring splits as the product of two rings, then it contains a non-trivial idempotent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The converse is easier: Suppose $R \approx A \times B$ as rings. Then $R$ is a direct product of two other rings, each with their own identity, $1_A$ and $1_B$. Both of these are non-trivial idempotents: $$1_A^2 = (1_A,0) \cdot (1_A,0) = (1_A^2,0) =(1_A,0)=1_A.$$

In particular, $1_A$ and $1_B$ are *orthogonal* idempotents, meaning that also $1_A 1_B = 1_B 1_A = 0$.

See also [this Tricki](http://www.tricki.org/article/Decompose_your_ring_using_idempotents) page.

**Added** I think I see where the confusion lies. Okay, here's how to define $R \times S$. Given an idempotent $e \in T$ (in your notation), you get another idempotent $1-e$ automatically ($s := (1-e)^2=1-2e+e=1-e$). Then let $R$ be the subring of $T$ generated by $e$ and $S$ the subring generated by $s$. Then we define a map $f:T \to R \times S$ by $g \mapsto (eg, sg)$. This is surjective (easy), and it is injective: for suppose $eg=0$ and $(1-e)g=0$. Then it follows trivially that $g=0$. So $f$ is an isomorphism. Thus, all of $R \times S$ used, there are no "subsets".

Comment: Dear Fredrik! Why it is the direct product of two rings? In my example, $f$ is an isomorphism but $T$ is not the direct product of $R$ and $S$.

Comment: @user139981 Okay, to be precise, it is isomorphic to a direct product, so working in $R$ or $A \times B$ is the same thing. Every ring property of $A \times B$ carries over to $R$ by the isomorphism.

Comment: Dear Fredrik! But in my example, $T$ is not isomorphic to the direct product $R\times S$, but just a subset of $R\times S$.

Comment: @user139981 Dear user, could you be more precise? In your question, you state that you have a map $f:T \to R \times S$ that is an isomorphism. You also say that "if a commutative ring splits as the product of two rings, then...". I don't see where my answer differs from your assumptions.

Comment: Dear Fredik, I understand your proof. Now the question becomes in the the proof of my original proof. I wanted to prove that if a commutative ring $T$ has a non-trivial idempotent $e$, then it is isomorphic to the direct product of two rings. However, $(et,(1-e)t)$ is only a subset of the direct product $R\times S$.

Comment: @user139981 How did you define $R \times S$

Comment: @user139981 I've adde some details to my answer.

Comment: Dear Fredrik! My question is on $f$ being surjective. $R \times S$ consists of elements like $(eg, sh)$, but the image of $f$ is only those $(eg, sg)$.

Comment: @user139981 Here's a proof of $f$ being surjective: Let $g=eg+sg$. Then $f(g)=(eg,sg)$.

Comment: Dear Fredrik! I don't get it. Do you mean all elements of $R \times S$ are of the form $(eg,sg)$?

Comment: No. All elements of $R \times S$ are of the form $(eg,sh)$ as you said, with $e,s$ being orthogonal idempotents. Then the element $eg+sh$ maps to $(eg,sh)$ (there was a typo in my previous comment)

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks!